# Token based authentication for log-in in Android Application

Tags: android, authentication, token

The application I am developing is a credit scoring application. This software should prevent unauthorized access. In order to implement this, I've used user and password-based authentication with two roles available - standard user and administrator.

This was implemented entirely in Python by using SQLAlchemy for interacting with the database, and Android for the user interface. For authentication, I am calling User Management System to get a token:

Request Body:

```
{
  "username": "credit_scoring",
  "password": "132465"
}
```

Response Body:

```
 {
    "apiData": {
        "navigationList": [],
        "userId": "credit_scoring",
        "userName": "credit_scoring",
        "email": "credit_scoring@erainfotechbd.com",
        "cellNo": "01255",
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOiJjcyIsIm5iZiI6MTY1OTUyNzcxOCwiZXhwIjoxNjYwMTMyNTE4LCJpYXQiOjE2NTk1Mjc3MThasdasd9.4lkEv-TpwIyYcldXfKucy3ynewhbuUFgjtdnKm7ymjE",
        "page": 0,
        "pageSize": 0,
        "searchString": null,
        "skip": 0
    },
    "message": "Record has been saved.",
    "isExecute": true,
    "totalRecord": 0
}
```

For security purposes, I have inserted some letters in the token. So currently, the token in this data is invalid.

Now, I want to save this token in the Android application and if the token is expired, then the user should be logged out from the application. How can I do that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your server should let u know if the token is  Expired with HTTP error code 401 . Then you can logout the User on device .. basically whenever u call any API with token Server should check the validity of token and respond accordingly ..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must answer a question what does it mean for you, that the user is logged out from a mobile app? This might mean:

- deleting the access token from the app's memory
- deleting any data about the user from memory (e.g., username, profile picture, etc.)
- maybe deleting the entries mentioned above from persistent storage, if these were not only kept in the memory, etc.

Once you have the logout logic implemented, you need a trigger for the logout itself. The best solution (in my opinion) will be to listen to 401 responses from your APIs and call logout when you get such a response. Another way is to check the expiration time of the access token (the `exp` claim contains expiration) and call logout when the token is expired. You can make such checks e.g., every time you make a call to the API, or set up an interval function (as you know the expiration time upfront you can set the logout event to trigger at the given time). Even if you decide to go with the second option, you will still need a mechanism to catch 401 responses from the API — responses from the backend should be your source of truth, not anything you calculate on the frontend (e.g., there might be clock skews present on the device, or the token might get revoked, etc.)